# jquery and bootstrap.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello people please help!

I have gone through all the jquery issues in stackoverflow. I tried some of the solutions but i am not getting the result as i want. I am making a one page website for my company but i am having trouble in bringing responsiveness to it.

The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Top Accountant. Providing solution for all your accounting needs</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- Navigation -->  
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Top Accountant</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#"class="dropdown-toggle" data-target=".dropdown">Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- End of Navigation -->  

<!--Image slider-->

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <!--images size should be 1920-741﻿ px -->
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/accountancy-services.png" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ut nisl sit amet est sodales imperdiet.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Contact Us</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/images.jpg" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ut nisl sit amet est sodales imperdiet.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Contact Us</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/accountant-9-tips.png"/>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ut nisl sit amet est sodales imperdiet.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Contact Us</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="Prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="Next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>

<!--End Image slider-->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

There are few things which i have made so far.

1.) When the website is viewed in mobile or tab the nav bar disappears and a toggle button appears. This is working fine.

2.) I have dropdown menu in services which is not working for me.
3.) I have made a carousel as well which is sliding perfectly but not responding to the the left and right click icon.

I don't know what's the problem as 1 is working fine but 2 & 3 are not working.

Please help me in this matter and advise me where am i going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please ask one question at a time and only include code relevant to what's not working

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Darren. I think it is problem with jquery which i am not able to figure it out. I thought it will be useful. Do you want me to edit my question??

Comment: check your console for any errors , also could you create a jsfiddle and replicate the same there, http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com) for working markup examples. There are few problems with your markup. Use `data-toggle="dropdown"` for the dropdown, and your href/class attributes are not spaced. Remove the `data-target` for the dropdown.

As far as the carousel goes, `next` and `prev` are case sensitive so you need to use `data-slide="prev"`. Also, since you're using `navbar-fixed-top` [don't forget to add](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top) `body {padding-top: 50px;}` or the navbar will overlay your carousel content.

Here's a working update:
http://codeply.com/go/gJvCndru8B

Comment: Thanks Skelly your suggestions were right. It was all spelling mistake and instead of data-toggle="dropdown" I had written data-target="dropdown"

Answer (score 0):

Replace your entire html code with this:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Top Accountant. Providing solution for all your accounting needs</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<!-- Navigation -->  
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Top Accountant</a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

                <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Services
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- End of Navigation -->  

<!--Image slider-->

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <!--images size should be 1920-741﻿ px -->
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/accountancy-services.png" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ut nisl sit amet est sodales imperdiet.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Contact Us</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/images.jpg" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ut nisl sit amet est sodales imperdiet.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Contact Us</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/accountant-9-tips.png"/>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ut nisl sit amet est sodales imperdiet.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Contact Us</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="Prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="Next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>

<!--End Image slider-->


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To repair your dropdown :

`data-toggle=".dropdown"` => `data-toggle="dropdown"` without the `.`

For the carousel, I don't understand your problem, but [take a look at the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)